# Read and edit specific value from json file in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, database, fs

I wanted to try to develop my own database with JS and Json. Unfortunately, I run into problems there.

How do I read specific content from the Json file
I googled and got this:

```js
fs.readFile('./databases/' + dbName + ".json", (err, data) => {
     if (err) throw err;
     content = JSON.parse(data);
     console.log(content)
});
```

But then I only get this output

```
{
  members: [
    { Username: 'User-1', Password: 'lol' },
    { Username: 'User-2', Password: 'lol' }
  ]
}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

and not a specific one, for example just the password of user-1 from the json file:

```json
{
  "members": [
    {
      "Username": "User-1",
      "Password": "lol"
    },
    {
      "Username": "User-2",
      "Password": "lol"
    }
    ]
}
```

(I really only want to use json files for this project)

Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

your question does not have much informations

```
fs.readFile("./databases/" + dbName + ".json", (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  var username = "User-1";
  var password = "lol";

  for (var i = 0; i < content.members.length; i++) {
    if (
      content.members[i].Username == username &&
      content.members[i].Password == password
    ) {
      console.log("Login Successful");
      return true;
    }
  }
  console.log("Login Failed");
  return false;
});
```

get the username and password fields from user side and use the for loop to validate the values are in the json database file

Answer (score 0):

As for storing data in a JSON-like object, databases already exist that offer great storage options out there for example [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/) or [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database).

As for your problem, the code is operating correctly what your looking for is a filter

```
fs.readFile('./databases/' + dbName + ".json", (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    const username = username;
    const password = password;

    //const username = "User-2";
    //const password = "lol";


    content = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(content.members.filter(mem => { if (mem.Username === username && mem.Password === password) return mem} ));
});
```

This will return:

```
[ { Username: 'User-2', Password: 'lol' } ]
```

You'll have you include a way to accept the username and password or any other filter variables you can think of.

Comment: Is it possible to only return the password? without the [{}]? and without username. or only the username.

Comment: Yes, you'd have to set what is in the console.log right now to a variable, then you could access it like a normal array. So if you set it to a const called member you could then console.log(member[0].Username); or any other part of that object you want, be warned this will return more than 1 object if a username and password match and only get the first item in the array we filtered.

Comment: oke thank you very much. But now I have one more question and I wanted to create my own database. I ask for the table in the function.

function readDB (dbName, tableName, where)

The entry in the database is called members, but I would like the user to be able to create their own table. so i tried that
and I replaced "members" with this variable

content.tableName.filter ()

and now get the error:

"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')
"

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. As for the filter function I'd read up on how it works because that can be tricky (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

As for your problem you have there, something is failing in content, "content.TableName" is not an array.

Comment: so i have to turn the json into an array?

Comment: Well, it seems whatever data you are getting from this new JSON file doesn't match the structure of your original file. You had an object with an item called "members" and that "members" was an array. Whatever in this new file you have is not an array, you'll have to keep data structures consistent or create different functions (copy of above) and modify them to match your data structure.

Comment: In the json file the section was called "members" so we went. But since I now after this surtitle in a variable it is no longer what I do not understand